# Database Join to connect 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Please have a look at the below diagram.

[image]

Here, I need to retrieve the `Investment_Type` of the `Portfolio` using the `idClient`. `Investment_Type` is a String in `Investment_Type` table.

Unfortunately, this database join is too complex for me :( . How can I achieve this task?

**PS:**

**In simple terms, what I need to do is; I need to get the list of `Clients` and see what are their `Portfolios` and the `portfolio_Type` of their each portfolio.**

Comment: What are all of the fields you need from the query result? Looks like each `idClient` can have many portfolios and thus many investment types, so what are your query parameters? Just an `idClient`?

Comment: @hukir: Yes, just the ID Client. In simple words, what I need to do is this; I need to get the list of "Clients" and see what are their "Portfolios" and the "portfolio_Type" of their each portfolio.

Comment: @hukir: `Client` can have many `Portfolios`. One `Portfolio` can have one `Investment_Type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Investment_Type
FROM Investment_Type
WHERE idInvestment_Type IN (
    SELECT idInvestment_Type
    FROM Portfolio
    WHERE idPortfolio IN (
         SELECT idPortfolio 
         FROM Client_Portfolio
         WHERE idClient IN ( SELECT idClient FROM Client)
         )
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below mentioned Query:

```
SELECT  IT.Investment_Type
FROM
Client_portFolio CF 
LEFT JOIN portfolio P ON (CF.idPorFolio = P.idPorFolio)
LEFT JOIN investment_type IT ON(P.idInvestmentType =IT.idInvestmentType)
WHERE CF.idClient = <ClientId>
```